# Not able to find Add New Data Source option in Visual studio 2010

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, entity-framework-4

I am using Entity Data Framework in my windows form. So i need to add a new data source. I go to the Visual studio 2010 professional main menu -> Data but there is no Add New Data Source option in Visual studio 2010 professional.

From where i can find Data Source connection wizard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a keyboard shortcut that points to `data.AddNewDataSource` within

> Tools -> Options -> Keyboard

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2012 :
Project-> Add New Data Source..

Visual Studio 2010:
Data-> Add New Data Source..

Answer (score 0):

Go to your windows form property > DataBindings > Advance ,click on tab(...). Binding property will open. Now click dropdown of bindings. Then click on "Add project datasource".

[image: click here to see picture]

Then choose your datasource.

[image: click here to see picture]